# Invoke client from the server?

Tags: python

I'm creating an application which consist of 1 Server and 2 Different clients.

The two clients communicate through the server. And was wondering how I from the server can 'invoke' a client.

The server has

```
s = socket.socket()
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(1)
```

and from what I've understood it's the s.listen(1) that waits for the client to send, and then the server can do some work. Is it possible to do the opposite aswell? Make a listener on the client for the server to invoke?

I haven't used any libraries other than socket and pickle.

Comment: What exactly are your plans?

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's exactly the definition of server and client.

But if you want to, and your "server" knows its "clients", they can exchange roles. But then their names change as well.

Having said that, it is perfectly possible to have a "client" at a fixed position and contact some servers which are carried around etc.

OTOH, it is as well possible to use an already existing protocol, but to use it "reversely" on a connection. This is because after establishing a connection, the functions of both ends are not fixed any longer; both ends have equal "rights" resp. possibilities. (I wouldn't go so far as to say they cannot be distinguished any longer, but I think it is quite hard...)

It completely depends on what you really want...

Comment: I was looking for some way to let the server tell one of the clients whenever the other client made a submit. But I could just go ahead and maybe run a function each 5 seconds to see if anything new is on the server?

Comment: Again, it depends on the protocol you use. Are the clients permanently connected to the server or do they just connect casually? For example the good old UUCP protocol is designed so that it can be initiated from both directions and then transfer data in both directions...

Comment: I use UCP. And the clients just connect casually yep.